# Using unix time function in QShell

Tags: unix, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to create a QShell command to output the time taken to complete a task. My command seems fine when I run it in cygwin, but doesn't produce anything in QShell. For example, this is the command I'd use to get the real time for ls

```
(time ls) 2>&1 | grep real | cut -f2 >> log.txt
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QSH is a Unix-like environment.  There are some oddities surrounding redirection.  IBM have a document called [Redirecting Output in Qshell](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas1ffd0d8a7e0475b1a862575c3005d8edf) that goes over this in brief.  I found the following to work, if clunky:

```
{ time ls *.txt; } > /dev/null 2> time.txt; grep real time.txt | cut -c10-20 >> log.txt; rm time.txt
```

I couldn't get STDERR redirected without going to a file.

Comment: Awesome Buck! It may be clunky but a clunky solution that works is better than all the non-clunky non-working "solutions".

Comment: Fantastic - thank you so much (I've spent hours on that one line of code)!!

Answer (score 1):

The difference here is `time` is a program in Cygwin but in QSHELL it's a built-in utility (like `echo`). I don't think you can redirect the output of built-in utilities.

To see if something is a built-in utility or a program you can use the `type` command.  For instance `type echo` will output:

```
echo is a shell built-in.
```

while `type time` will output:

```
time is a reserved word.
```

You can also look at the contents of /usr/bin. `ls /usr/bin/t*`:

```
/usr/bin/tail    /usr/bin/test        /usr/bin/tr
/usr/bin/tar     /usr/bin/tnameserv
/usr/bin/tee     /usr/bin/touch
```

In Cygwin (or in my case, on a Linux box) type `which time` and you'll get

```
/usr/bin/time
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a quirk related to qshell, subshells and/or the native `time` utility.

**QSH**

```
===> time ls
  test_file

  real    0m0.054384s
  user    0m0.054384s
  sys     0m0.000000s

===> (time ls)
  test_file
```

It works fine using [PASE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzalf/rzalfintro.htm):

**QP2TERM**

```
===> time ls
  test_file

  real    0m0.10s
  user    0m0.01s
  sys     0m0.02s

===> (time ls)
  test_file

  real    0m0.14s
  user    0m0.01s
  sys     0m0.02s
```